# How do i use a CMake Macro in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake

How do I use a CMake macro in a project to buld it. Specifically, I have a cmake file that I'm trying to build a kde4 plugin for. I'm trying to use the KDE4_ADD_PLUGIN macro but when I run cmake its not finding it. How do I configure CMake to find this Macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss some include to KDE CMake modules. I haven't checked it, but you should try something like:

```
# Find the required Libaries
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
include(KDE4Defaults)
```